# Is there a way to get the current object and method with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, object, methods

I'm looking for a function that would tell me the current object and method by way of the URI.  Normally, I would use `$this->uri->uri_string()`, however, I do not want to pass any "dynamic" segments.  For example, a URI of `'products/shoes/123'`, would be `'products/view_product'`.

I want to be able to do this so I can create a config file containing page titles... since I use a model to output my page header.  It is called from `MY_Controller.php` in the construct.  For example: `$this->template->overall_header($title = "View Product")...`

but in the construct, it would be:

$`this->template->overall_header($title = $this->config->item($object_method_string));`

Anybody have any solutions?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: what do you mean by object here...the parameter passed in method?????

Answer (score 0):

for current method

   `$method= $this->router->fetch_method();`

I hope you are talking about this

Answer (score 0):

To expand on **Nishant's** answer you can access the attributes from the router class.

So for current object;

```
$this->router->class
```

And for current method;

```
$this->router->method
```